# OpenSSL pads keys in aes encryption?

Tags: openssl, aes

I'm trying to use aes-128-cbc encryption with openssl, and I would expect that the key needs to be 32 digits. However, I noticed that when I put in a key length of 18, openssl does not give me an error.

```
echo hello | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -A -a -nosalt -K 123456789012345678 -iv 66666666666666666666666666666666

output:zBN+65infn74QK+prfY6kw==
```

But if I add 0's after the key until it's 32 digits, I still get the same result.

```
echo hello | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -A -a -nosalt -K 12345678901234567800000000000000 -iv 6666666666666666666666666666666

output:zBN+65infn74QK+prfY6kw==
```

Is there documentation anywhere that says OpenSSL adds padding to keys?

Edit: I need to reproduce this behavior in code. I'm given the key, but there is no guarantee on how many digits the key will be.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Not every behavior is always described. Now that you asked this question, you've also documented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES with a 128-bit key is a 16-byte or 32 hex digit key. It is probably zero padding the unspecified part of the key, **do not rely on key padding**, that is unspecified behavior.

It is always best to provide the exact size inputs to encryption functions, specify 32 hex digits for an AES 128-bit key.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, OpenSSL will print a warning saying `hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length` if your key or IV is too short.

However, it doesn't mention how (prepending or appending).

Luckily, you can use `-p` to see the exact keys and IVs OpenSSL is using.

Apparently, it's appending zeros to the right.

```sh
>openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -K 614c9b1fa9ea1b1be878929c592d -iv 0276 -nosalt -in enc -out dec -p
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
key=614C9B1FA9EA1B1BE878929C592D0000
iv =02760000000000000000000000000000
```